# Graph Theory: Nontrivial tree has independent sets.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every nontrivial tree has at least two maximal independent sets, with equality only for stars.

Since a tree has no cycles, it has no odd cycles. Hence it is bipartite so, by definition, it has at least two independent sets. From here, I am not sure how to show that the independent sets are maximal, nor why equality is only for stars.

Answer (score 6):

When you prove that the tree is bipartite, you split the vertices in two groups $V=V_1 \cup V_2$. Now $V_1, V_2$ are maximal because the tree is connected: if lets say $V_1$ would not be maximal, you could add some vertex to it to get an independent set. But that vertex would be a vertex from $V_2$, and then it is connected to some other vertex, which must be in $V_1$, which shows that you don't have an independent set.

As for the second part, If $V=V_1 \cup V_2$ and each $V_i$ has at least 2 elements, show that you can find some $x \in V_1, y \in V_2$ so that $xy$ is not an edge. Then $\{ x, y \}$ is independent, and then there exists a maximal independent set containing it.

Comment: I am still confused about how to show that a star has only 2 maximal independent sets. Or am I completely misinterpreting the question?

Comment: In $K_{1,n}$, if we include the vertex of degree $n$ in the independent set, we can include no others (without violating the independent set condition).  If we include $m<n$ of the vertices of degree $1$, then it's not maximial (we can add in the remaining $n-m$ vertices into the independent set to create a larger independent set).